# how to compress the width and height of the image without cropping in 500 x 500

Tags: php, html

I am able to crop the image as 500 x 500 px after uploading using php. But, the problem is the image is getting cropped if it is compressed. I want the full image to be compressed or resized in 500 x 500 without cropping. Please help. I am providing my code for reference.

```
function resize_image($file, $width, $height) {
    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($file);

    /* calculate new image size with ratio */
    $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
    $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
    $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
    $w = ceil($width / $ratio);

    /* read binary data from image file */
    $imgString = file_get_contents($file);

    /* create image from string */
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
        0, 0,
        $x, 0,
        $width, $height,
        $w, $h);
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

    //$ext will be gif

    imagejpeg($tmp, $file, 100);
    return $file;

    /* cleanup memory */

    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
}
```

Comment: btw - your function returns `$file` before `imagedestroy();` so the latter two calls to imagedestry will never get called..

Comment: Also, if you do not want the image to be cropped why set a value for $x in your example (`imagecopyresampled`) - that will set the x-position of source image. Surely, if you do not want recropping that ought to be 0?

Comment: You do realise that picking an arbitrary size of 500x500 without respecting the orignal size is likely to cause the image to get distorted dont you?